# Sans-Serif fonts with long descenders

Tags: fonts, font-identification, sans-serif

I am need of a typeface with descenders that match or come close to the x-height. Can you recommend some?

System fonts or free fonts would be ideal.

Answer (score 6):

A visual search in [dafont's](http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=501) or [Font Squirrel's sans-serif section](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/style/Sans%20Serif) one will probably give you better results.

Fontscape has a [section with long descenders](http://www.fontscape.com/explore?NDD), but they are paid fonts.

These are some of the ones I found, they look very similar, but I'm sure you can find lots more if you do a search.

- [Elegant Light](http://www.dafont.com/elegantlight.font?fpp=50):

[image]
[image]

---

- [Thin Lines and Curves](http://www.dafont.com/thin-lines-and-curves.font?fpp=50)

[image]
[image]

---

- [Mamma Gamma](http://www.dafont.com/mamma-gamma.font?fpp=50)

[image]
[image]

Comment: @IanGraham yisela has done her best here to keep it to freeware. But notice the difference between the free fonts and the commercial font I recommended. Those freebies are all quite clumsy. For $45 USD, Canterbury (or many other commercial fonts) would make your work look professional. In the same sense, a client *can* get design work for free or next to nothing but would they want to?

Comment: @plainclothes Yes, I agree. People giving fonts for free make their best effort with the resources they have. At the same time, it's always good to support the professional designers.

Answer (score 3):

**[Canterbury Sans](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/redrooster/canterbury-sans/)** takes the height a step further. Since it's basically mono-weight, it would be a simple matter to compress the extender lengths for a logotype or headline.

[image]

[image]

Comment: [I can go one step further](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontdiner/coffee-shop/)

Comment: That's shameful!

Comment: Hush, that font is *gorgeous.* :)